# variable variables, the key to my array

Tags: php, arrays, variable-variables

I found an example [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) that shows an example like this:

```
<?php 
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; $i++) {
  ${a.$i} = "value";
}    

echo "$a1, $a2, $a3, $a4, $a5";
//Output is value, value, value, value, value
?>
```

Is it possible to modify it to work like this:

```
for($x=1; $x<11; $x++)
{
    ${title.$x} = $row['${title.$x}'];
    ${brief.$x} = $row['${brief.$x}'];
    ${cost.$x} = $row['${cost.$x}'];

    echo "<tr>
               <td>${title.$x}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
               <td>${brief.$x}</td>
          </tr>
         ";
 }
```

The $row array comes from a mysql query.

Comment: Seriously, does every row contain 10 titles, 10 briefs and 10 costs fields???

Comment: Move the quotes when referencing your `$row` - `$row[${'title'.$x}];`

Comment: You badly need to look at your database design. Why are `title1` `title2` ... not separate rows?

Comment: YES! my rows have ten data fields! it is normalized though. One date has up to ten parts and a title for each part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for($x=1; $x<11; $x++)
{
    ${'title'.$x} = $row['title'.$x]; // will be like: $title1 = $row['title1']; (if you mean that)
    ${'brief'.$x} = $row['brief'.$x];
    ${'cost'.$x} = $row['cost'.$x];

    echo "<tr>
               <td>${'title'.$x}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
               <td>${'brief'.$x}</td>
          </tr>
         ";
 }
```

If your variable name is same with the key name in the `$row`, you could use `extract($row)` to get all variables you want.

But in your case, I think using the `$row` array directly is not bad idea.

Comment: the code speaks for itself, but it wants some words of wisdom to accompany it

Comment: @Kristian Added a comment, it's easy to understand.

Comment: I have changed it to use the $row array only... I see the redundancy HAHA. Thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are ok with converting everything in `$row` to a variable, the simplest way is to use PHP's [extract()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) (converts an array into variables), by just writing `extract($row);`